# Change attribute value in XML

Tags: php, xml, forms, attributes

Im working in a code for several days and I can't find how to change the value of an attribute in XML from PHP. I have an XML about books, where the principal element is BOOK and it has an attribute called status whose value now is AVAILABLE. So, the client bought some books choosing from a multiple select form(BOOKS)and now I need to change their attributes to NOT AVAILABLE. I need to do it from PHP so this is the code I tried that obviously is not working at all:

MY XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="html/xsl" href="books.xsl"?>
<books>
    <book cod="1" status='not available'>
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
        <isbn>123</isbn>
        <author>JK Rowling</author>
        <year>2001</year>
    
     </book>   


     <book cod="2" status='available'>
        <title>Wonder</title>
        <isbn>987</isbn>
        <author>Stephen Chbosky</author>
        <year>2017</year>
     </book>

     <book cod="2" status='available'>
        <title>Les Miserables</title>
        <isbn>654</isbn>
        <author>Victor Hugo</author>
        <year>1862</year>
     </book>
   
     
</books>
```

MY CODE:

```
$all=simplexml_load_file("thebooks.xml");
foreach($all as $values){

 if((string) $values["status"]=="available"){

    $availables[]=($values->title);
    
    
   <form action="receipt.php" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" 
   method="POST">

        <SELECT MULTIPLE name="books[]">
        <?php
            foreach($availables as $av){ ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $av?>"><?php echo $av?></option>
                
            <?php }
      ?>
        </SELECT>

        

    <input type="submit" value="choose" name="send"/>

    <?php
  }
 if(isset($_POST["send"])){

            $chosen=$_POST["books"];

            foreach($shop as $value){

                for($i=0; $i<count($chosen); $i++){

                    if((string) $value["status"]==(String)$chosen[$i]){

                        $value["status"]=="not available";
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    ?>
```

**Thank you everyone in advance and sorry for the d*irty code, im new working with XML**

Comment: Why not to use XSL for the task?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.

Comment: One thing is that `$value["status"]=="not available"` is not an assignment.

Comment: Thank you Nigel Ren, it was a silly mistake, I changed it but it doesnt work yet. I added my XML code to clarify.